# onmouseover and click event QLineEdit

Tags: qt, qlineedit

How can I define `onmouseover` and click event for a `QLineEdit`? I want to make 2 signals as `onmouseover()` and `clicked()` for `QLineEdit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, you'll have to inherit `QLineEdit` and override `void  mouseMoveEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )` and `void   mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )` (or `void  mouseReleaseEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )` if you wish). And don't forget to call `setMouseTracking(true);` to track mouse moves, when no mouse button is held.

Answer (score 3):

You can install an [event filter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) on your QLineEdit.

Here's an example:

```
QLineEdit *line_edit = new QLineEdit(this);
ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(line_edit);
line_edit->installEventFilter(this);
```

And in your event filter function you can do something like this: (This is a function you override)

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        qDebug() << "CLICK";
    }
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        qDebug() << "MOUSE OVER";
    }
    return false;
}
```